# React Router - Use component parameter and pass in props to rendered component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Using a dynamic approach to routing using a component parameter instead of render.

```
<Route
path={prop.layout + prop.path}
component={prop.component}
key={key}/>
```

prop.component comes in as a component object of the form:

`import Environments from "views/core/Environments.jsx";
prop.component=Environments;`

While preserving this approach, I want to be able to pass a prop (props) into the component. Is this doable without changing the current routing setup?

Thank you,

Edit: Thanks Lopoi, appreciate your help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform `prop.component` into a function with the props as one object input, and the component you want to return as output

```js
prop.component = (props) => {
   return <Environments {...props}/>;
}
```

However, the route would need to provide the input to the function `component={prop.component(props)}`

In case you are running a `forEach`or `map` loop, and `prop.component` is just a reference to a component you can use [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) to build that element as **children** of the `Route` like:

```js
<Route
path={prop.layout+prop.path}
key={key}
>
 {React.createElement(prop.component,props)}
</Route>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! That part I wasn't too sure on.. that is, the component={prop.component(props)}  as prop.component is an object of an array of prop.components[Environments, Users, ContactUs, etc].  If I hardcoded I could do it as you mentioned <Environments {...props}/>, but right now not sure how to handle it being just an Environment object, if that makes sense? Do you know if that is doable in the current design?

Comment: Are the components `Environments, Users, etc` functions or classes?

Comment: They are classes

Comment: You can use [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) to avoid the hardcode. Also is `prop` an item from an array that is going through a `forEach`or `map`method?

Comment: ah thank you! I think it's just a single-value integer (that is pulled from an array at some point though).  will get into createElement now.. been unsure of how to handle this for a while, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hi Lopoi, I tried this but am getting: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.  

However, getting this further up the chain. I realized I left this out of the original description as didn't think it was relevant, but my index.js is doing routing at a higher-level as below. AdminLayout contains the code we discussed above though:
 <Router history={hist}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/auth/login" render={props => <AuthLayout {...props} />} />

Comment: @MatthewHolt it might be because Route Component expects a path to a component, but not the built compoent. Maybe Doing `<Route>{React.createElement()}</Route>` or using the [function parameter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/children-func) should fix it